# Java: Why is this code not working?

Tags: java

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this Java code?
This array is : `static String [][] data = new String[6][2];` But in this case, `data[0][1]="abcd"` and `data[1][1]="efgh"`, the remaining `data[2-5][1]` should be `null`. I am just trying to print out the non-`null` ones. At `(j=2,k=3)`, the code doesn't get executed after that. For eg, the "I am here3" doesn't get printed.

```
int k=1;  
System.out.println("data[2][0]="+data[2][0]);  

for(int j=0; j<data.length; j++,k++) {
    System.out.println("j="+j+" k="+k);

    if (!(data[j][0].equals("null"))) {
        System.out.println("I am here2");
        sbissues = sbissues.append("\n");
        sbissues = sbissues.append(k);
        sbissues = sbissues.append(".  ");
        sbissues = sbissues.append(data[j][1]);
    }

    System.out.println("sbissues="+sbissues.toString());
    System.out.println("I am here1");
}
System.out.println("I am here3");
```

The output looks like:

```
data[2][0]=null  
j=0 k=1  
I am here2  
sbissues=  
1.  abcd  
I am here1  
j=1 k=2  
I am here2  
sbissues=  
1.  abcd  
2.  efgh  
I am here1  
j=2 k=3
```

The problem is that i never reach the "I am here3".
Thanks guys for the answers, they are all correct (to use !=null instead of .equals). I guess i can't vote for all of you, i'm just allowed to vote once.

Comment: what was the expected result of the above code?

Comment: is there any errors? i see no errors if you are getting output, what are you trying to do?

Comment: ... and how is `data` defined? (or what is its content)

Comment: Yeah I don't see anything wrong with it, its behaving exactly as I would expect

Comment: This array is : static String [][] data = new String[6][2]; But in this case, data[0][1]="abcd" and data[1][1]="efgh", the remaining should be null. I am just trying to print out the non-null ones. At (j=2,k=3), the code doesn't get executed after that.

Comment: I see this question has been subject to StackOverflow's firing squad...

Comment: @sthupahs ... or rather a bunch of bored people doing their best to guess the intention of OP, help him and win the Who Knows What He Means Contest; although he didn't put his heart into the question.

Comment: @stumped: You are allowed to accept only one answer, but you may vote more than once (by clicking the "Up" arrow to the left of an answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you don't want it printing anything when it's null.

Use this for your if statement instead:

```
if (data[j][0] != null) {
```

In java complex variables are references to objects. You can have two variables pointing to the same object. When a variable is pointing to nothing then it's null. You cannot dereference a null variable, that's when you get a NullPointerException.

The primitive data types like int, long, byte, etc. behave differently. Every time you assign you're making a copy of the data. They cannot be null.

Comment: Thanks, that works! But why?? Since data[j][0] is of type String, shouldn't i use data[j][0].equals(null), instead of !=

Comment: `null` doesn't have the `equals()` method. `null` is not an `Object` or something. It's simply **nothing**. Any attempt to access/invoke it using period operator `.` will only result in `NullPointerException` (does the exception name now have a more sensible meaning to you?)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you iterate in only one dimension (with both `j` and `k` variables). I guess you wanted to iterate over two dimensions of your data structure (thus you would need pretty much two `for` loops). So I would start with something like:

```
 for (int j=0; j<data.length; j++) {
     for (int k=0; k<data[j].length; k++) {
          // ... here goes the printing
     }
 }
```

Comment: I missed it at first, but the OP is incrementing k in j's for loop. I first though he wanted to do what you are saying but then I looked at the usages of k, and it seems they are not intended to be a second level index into his data array, it is more like a 1-based counter.

Comment: While `k` appears to be useless, the array seems to have dimensions of [n][2]. It looks like each element in the array is a key-value pair.

Comment: Yes, I saw `k` is always `j+1` but I guess this wasn't the OP's intention. I guess we'll never know.

Answer (score 0):

Like others, I am unsure what your code is trying to do. From what I can tell though, there are a few errors we should be fixed. Maybe fixing these will make it do what you want.

First...

```
if (!(data[j][0].equals("null"))) {
```

This should be...

```
if (data[j][0] != null) {
```

Second...

In your if check, you are checking if `data[j][0]` is null. Then, on the last line in the if block, you are using `data[j][1]`. I am guessing these should be the same, not different indexes? Or maybe you wanted to use `k` to index in?

Last...

You are re-using the StringBuilder instance for every iteration. The `toString()` method does not flush it's buffer. If you are expecting to output different things, try flushing the SB instance at the end of each loop iteration. If you are intending to append on to any existing string, then you are doing it right.

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting a `NullPointerException`. Did you post all of your output? Are you redirecting stdout or stderr when running your program?

---

The OP comments,

> Thanks, that works! But why?? Since data[j][0] is of type String, shouldn't i use data[j][0].equals(null), instead of !=

No, because if `data[j][0]` is `null`, trying to invoke `equals()` on it will raise a `NullPointerException`. You can't access the methods or fields of an object that doesn't exist.

By the way, this `NullPointerException` should have been visible in your output. Did you see anything like it?

Comment: Hi erickson, No, i had not seen the NullPointerException on the Console, just all my print statements. It is a Junit test on Eclipse.

Comment: @stumped - If you click on the failed test in the JUnit pane, you should be able to see the `NullPointerException` stack trace. (I think; I use TestNG, but I think their UIs are similar.)

Answer (score 0):

To start with, if `str == null`, then

```
str.equals("null")
```

generates a `NullPointerException`. So you may want to change

```
if (!(data[j][0].equals("null"))) {
```

into

```
if (data[j][0] != null) {
```

---

Then, given the initialization

```
data[2][0] = "hello";
data[2][1] = "world";
```

The program will print (I removed the `"I am here"`s):

```
data[2][0]=hello
j=0 k=1
sbissues=
j=1 k=2
sbissues=
j=2 k=3
sbissues=
3.  world
j=3 k=4
sbissues=
3.  world        <----
j=4 k=5
sbissues=
3.  world
j=5 k=6
sbissues=
3.  world
```

---

The reason you don't get any output for the case

```
data[0][1]="abcd"
data[1][1]="efgh"
        ^ both values put in column 1 (will not affect the data[j][0] check!)
```

is because you only append stuff to `sbissues` if column 0 is non-null.

In the above assignments you only set a value for column 1, i.e., no rows in your matrix will trigger the if-statements.